# Open VPN calling a script: Unrecognized option: [AF_INET]

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, openvpn

**Netgear R7000 Router
Tomato v1.28.0000 -2017.2-kille72- K26ARM USB AIO-64K**

I could do with some help debugging my script.

Goal: retrieve forwarded port number from VPN API JSON, pass port number to running transmission daemon using transmission-remote.

My input:

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
#
# Enable port forwarding when using Private Internet Access
#
# Usage:
#  ./port_forwarding.sh
set -x
exec 5>/etc/openvpn/mylog
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '

TRANSUSER=me
TRANSPASS=mypass
TRANSHOST=192.168.1.251

/bin/echo waiting 20s for vpn to connect and trasmission to start
sleep 20

error( )
{
  /bin/echo "$@" 1>&2
  exit 1
}

error_and_usage( )
{
  /bin/echo "$@" 1>&2
  usage_and_exit 1
}

usage( )
{
  /bin/echo "Usage: `dirname $0`/$PROGRAM"
}

usage_and_exit( )
{
  usage
  exit $1
}

version( )
{
  /bin/echo "$PROGRAM version $VERSION"
}


port_forward_assignment( )
{
  client_id_file="/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id"
  if [ ! -f "$client_id_file" ]; then
    if hash /opt/bin/shasum 2>/dev/null; then
      /usr/bin/head -n 100 /dev/urandom | /opt/bin/shasum -a 256 | tr -d " -" > "$client_id_file"
    elif hash /opt/bin/sha256sum 2>/dev/null; then
      /usr/bin/head -n 100 /dev/urandom | /opt/bin/sha256sum | tr -d " -" > "$client_id_file"
    else
      /bin/echo "Please install shasum or sha256sum, and make sure it is visible in your \$PATH"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  client_id=`/bin/cat "$client_id_file"`
  json=`/opt/bin/curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null`
  if [ "$json" == "" ]; then
    json='Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding'
  fi

  /bin/echo server returned message: $json

#trim VPN forwarded port from JSON
PORT=$(echo $json | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{r=1;FS="[{}\":]+"} /port/{r=0; print $3} END{exit r}')
/bin/echo if succesful port is:$PORT  

#change transmission port on the fly

/opt/bin/transmission-remote $TRANSHOST --auth $TRANSUSER:$TRANSPASS -p "$PORT"
/bin/echo your transmission details: $TRANSHOST $TRANSUSER $TRANSPASS
}

/bin/echo remember to reconnect to VPN before running this script. Run no longer than 2 minutes after connection or this will fail!

EXITCODE=0
PROGRAM=`basename $0`
VERSION=2.1

while /usr/bin/test $# -gt 0
do
  case $1 in
  --usage | --help | -h )
    usage_and_exit 0
    ;;
  --version | -v )
    version
    exit 0
    ;;
  *)
    error_and_usage "Unrecognised option: $1"
    ;;
  esac
  shift
done

port_forward_assignment

exit 0
```

Problem: When I run this script from shell it works fine, but when I call the script in my openvpn config I get this result:

```
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
12: TRANSUSER=me
13: TRANSPASS=mypass
14: TRANSHOST=192.168.1.251
16: /bin/echo waiting 20s for vpn to connect and trasmission to start
17: sleep 20
79: /bin/echo remember to reconnect to VPN before running this script. Run no longer than 2 minutes after connection or this will 'fail!'
81: EXITCODE=0
882: basename /etc/openvpn/test.sh
82: PROGRAM=test.sh
83: VERSION=2.1
85: /usr/bin/test 1 -gt 0
87: case $1 in
96: error_and_usage 'Unrecognized option: [AF_INET]45.136.190.211 1198'
27: /bin/echo 'Unrecognized option: [AF_INET]46.136.190.211 1198'
28: usage_and_exit 1
38: usage
333: dirname /etc/openvpn/test.sh
33: /bin/echo 'Usage: /etc/openvpn/test.sh'
39: exit 1
```

Works fine when run in shell though:

```
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
12: TRANSUSER=me
13: TRANSPASS=mypass
14: TRANSHOST=192.168.1.251
16: /bin/echo waiting 20s for vpn to connect and trasmission to start
17: sleep 20
79: /bin/echo remember to reconnect to VPN before running this script. Run no longer than 2 minutes after connection or this will 'fail!'
81: EXITCODE=0
882: basename ./test.sh
82: PROGRAM=test.sh
83: VERSION=2.1
85: /usr/bin/test 0 -gt 0
102: port_forward_assignment
50: client_id_file=/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
51: '[' '!' -f /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id ']'
661: /bin/cat /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
61: client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426223e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232
662: /opt/bin/curl 'http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232'
62: json='{"port":44257}'
63: '[' '{"port":44257}' == '' ']'
67: /bin/echo server returned message: '{"port":44257}'
770: echo '{"port":44257}'
770: /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{r=1;FS="[{}\":]+"} /port/{r=0; print $3} END{exit r}'
70: PORT=44257
71: /bin/echo if successful port is:44257
75: /opt/bin/transmission-remote 192.168.1.251 --auth me:mypass -p 44257
76: /bin/echo your transmission details: 192.168.1.251 me mypass
104: exit 0
```

Where am I going wrong? Why does this fail when script is called by OpenVPN and not when I run in shell? How can I find out what AF_INET points too? Strangely the IP address in the error is my client VPN server and port, not the forwarded port number returned from the JSON.

My OpenVPN config:

```
# Automatically generated configuration
daemon
client
dev tun11
proto udp
remote nl.privateinternetaccess.com 1198
resolv-retry 30
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo adaptive
ncp-ciphers AES-128-GCM:AES-256-GCM:AES-128-CBC:AES-256-CBC
cipher AES-128-CBC
redirect-gateway def1
verb 3
script-security 2
up updown.sh
down updown.sh
ca ca.crt
status-version 2
status status

# Custom Configuration
syslog [progname]
persist-key
persist-tun
tls-client
auth-user-pass /tmp/password.txt
comp-lzo
verb 3
reneg-sec 0
ipchange "/etc/openvpn/test.sh"
script-security 3
```

EDIT#

Thanks to Ipor Sircer below I managed to avoid the error by not defining argument 1. My input now looks like this (for simplication) but my output when called by OpenVPN is very different than when I run the script directly.

My input:

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
#
# Enable port forwarding when using Private Internet Access
#
# Usage:
#  ./port_forwarding.sh
set -x
exec 5>/etc/openvpn/mylog
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"
PS4='$LINENO: '

TRANSUSER=me
TRANSPASS=mypass
TRANSHOST=192.168.1.251

  client_id_file="/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id"
  if [ ! -f "$client_id_file" ]; then
    if hash /opt/bin/shasum 2>/dev/null; then
      /usr/bin/head -n 100 /dev/urandom | /opt/bin/shasum -a 256 | tr -d " -" > "$client_id_file"
    elif hash /opt/bin/sha256sum 2>/dev/null; then
      /usr/bin/head -n 100 /dev/urandom | /opt/bin/sha256sum | tr -d " -" > "$client_id_file"
    else
      /bin/echo "Please install shasum or sha256sum, and make sure it is visible in your \$PATH"
      exit 1
    fi
  fi
  client_id=`/bin/cat "$client_id_file"`
  json=`/opt/bin/curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null`
  if [ "$json" == "" ]; then
    json='Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding'
  fi

  /bin/echo server returned message: $json

#trim VPN forwarded port from JSON
PORT=$(echo $json | /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{r=1;FS="[{}\":]+"} /port/{r=0; print $3} END{exit r}')
/bin/echo if successful port is:$PORT  

#change transmission port on the fly

/opt/bin/transmission-remote $TRANSHOST --auth $TRANSUSER:$TRANSPASS -p "$PORT"
/bin/echo your transmission details: $TRANSHOST $TRANSUSER $TRANSPASS
```

Output with OpenVPN:

```
+ PS4='$LINENO: '
12: TRANSUSER=me
13: TRANSPASS=pass
14: TRANSHOST=192.168.1.251
16: client_id_file=/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
17: '[' '!' -f /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id ']'
227: /bin/cat /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
27: client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232
228: /opt/bin/curl 'http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232'
28: json=
29: '[' '' == '' ']'
30: json='Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding'
33: /bin/echo server returned message: Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding
336: echo Port forwarding is already activated on this connection, has expired, or you are not connected to a PIA region that supports port forwarding
336: /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{r=1;FS="[{}\":]+"} /port/{r=0; print $3} END{exit r}'
36: PORT=
37: /bin/echo if successful port is:
41: /opt/bin/transmission-remote 192.168.1.251 --auth me:pass -p ''
42: /bin/echo your transmission details: 192.168.1.251 me pass
```

Without OpenVPN:

```
16: client_id_file=/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
17: '[' '!' -f /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id ']'
227: /bin/cat /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
27: client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232
228: /opt/bin/curl 'http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232'
28: json='{"port":44257}'
29: '[' '{"port":44257}' == '' ']'
33: /bin/echo server returned message: '{"port":44257}'
336: echo '{"port":44257}'
336: /usr/bin/awk 'BEGIN{r=1;FS="[{}\":]+"} /port/{r=0; print $3} END{exit r}'
36: PORT=44257
37: /bin/echo if successful port is:44257
```

Answer (score 2):

Openvpn call your script with 2 parameters which you've defined as unrecognized option.

man openvpn:

"--ipchange cmd

Run command cmd when our remote ip-address is initially  authen‐
              ticated or changes.

cmd  consists  of  a  path  to  script  (or executable program),
              optionally followed by arguments. The path and arguments may  be
              single-  or  double-quoted and/or escaped using a backslash, and
              should be separated by one or more spaces.

When cmd is executed **two arguments are appended after any  arguments specified in cmd**, as follows:

cmd **ip_address port_number**"

Comment: thank you so much! I wrongly assumed there were no arguments passed, the same as the up and down commands.

Comment: Problem I am having now is the line:  `json=/opt/bin/curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null`
is working fine to retrieve the port number from JSON but **not** when the script is called by openVPN. How can I debug this?

Comment: I provided the answer to your JSON problem but a moderator deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that `json` is empty is because `curl` fails.

The reason that `curl` fails is because; as a security measure (therefore *by design*), OpenVPN will not allow any packets to traverse the tunnel while **any** script which was started by the `openvpn` binary is still executing.

You will need to find another method to invoke your script.

**This is why this is the correct answer and why this answer should not be deleted:**

The client is connecting to `remote nl.privateinternetaccess.com 1198`

VPN Service provider servers *typically* redirect **all** traffic over the VPN.

In the `--ipchange script` we find this command: `` json=`/opt/bin/curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null` ``

Therefore: `curl http://209.222.18.222:2000 etc` is trying to use the VPN to connect to `IP 209.222.18.222` and openvpn will **not** allow any packets to pass over the VPN until **all** scripts have completed.

This has also been asked and answered @ https://forums.openvpn.net/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=25114#p73956

Note: I have gone to great lengths to verify that this answer is accurate while https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/257736/dodgexander has not responded to any of the answers received here or at openvpn.net