# curl not receiving JSON in open vpn

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, openvpn, curl

**Netgear R7000 router running Tomato v1.28.0000 -2017.2-kille72- K26ARM USB AIO-64K**

Goal: receive port number from JSON using curl

When I run this script in shell it works, but not when I call the script in my OpenVPN config.

```
#!/opt/bin/bash
#
# Enable port forwarding when using Private Internet Access
#
# Usage:
#  ./port_forwarding.sh
set -x
exec 5>/etc/openvpn/mylog
BASH_XTRACEFD="5"

sleep 10

  client_id_file="/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id"
  client_id=$(/bin/cat "$client_id_file")
  json=$(/opt/bin/curl "http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=$client_id" 2>/dev/null)
  /bin/echo server returned message: "$json"
```

Output from shell:

```
+ sleep 10
+ client_id_file=/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
++ /bin/cat /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
+ client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232
++ /opt/bin/curl 'http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232'
+ json='{"port":44257}'
+ /bin/echo server returned message: '{"port":44257}'
```

Output from OpenVPN:

```
+ sleep 10
+ client_id_file=/etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
++ /bin/cat /etc/openvpn/pia_client_id
+ client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232
++ /opt/bin/curl 'http://209.222.18.222:2000/?client_id=080db0a6e936918d405683447a78bf426273e9a1ea2ecce744722ac3241d4232'
+ json=
+ /bin/echo server returned message: ''
```

More details from previous question: [Open VPN calling a script: Unrecognized option: [AF_INET]](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/400905/open-vpn-calling-a-script-unrecognized-option-af-inet)

Comment: I can't delete the original but I deleted the last question I asked which points to this

Comment: Is there an environment variable (proxy??) that your user has that openvpn is lacking or overwriting?

Comment: Where’s the output from the openvpn version?

Comment: You might consider dropping the 2>/dev/null temporarily just to see if there are insightful errors.

Comment: Did you simply not paste the same amount of debug output from the working version?

Comment: Not sure on the environment variable, the version of OpenVPN I am using is baked into the firmware. Any way I can check? No error displayed when I remove 2>/dev/null sadly. Same output.

Comment: The debug info of the working version is added above with removing 2>/dev/null.

Comment: Openvpn may discard the output; perhaps save it to a file instead? See if your environment has any of the [variables that curl uses](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Comment: Just seems fishy that the output from the manual run doesn’t have the sleep or client_id_file output.

Comment: Sorry! It was a copy and paste from terminal, I have now added the full output. curl seems to support all the variables.

Comment: Why are you deleting your older questions?

Comment: @SatōKatsura someone requested I did as this was a simplified version of the original.

Answer (score 2):

The reason that `json` is empty is because `curl` fails.

The reason that `curl` fails is because; as a security measure (therefore *by design*), OpenVPN will not allow any packets to traverse the tunnel while **any** script which was started by the `openvpn` binary is still executing.

You will need to find another method to invoke your script.